# white lines in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

I am new to blender and I love it.
This model now for some reason has white dashed lines all over it and some solid black lines too. I know the black lines are supposed to be there but i have no idea how the other lines got there, I must have clicked something but have no idea what i have done. Please help[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your edges are marked as Sharp. In the "T" menu, go to Shading/UV, select all edges (A), then click Smooth.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That did the trick. There sure is so much to still learn.

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you please mark my answer as the accepted solution?